# Encryption in transit for Remote backend i.e. s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-remote-state

I can see lot of questions regarding encryption at rest for storing state file using remote backend in terraform e.g. s3, but like to confirm; Does terraform uses ssh/tls to securely transfer/read the state files during this process.

Though we can use TLS provider to achieve that but like the official version since i cannot find anything useful in the documentation.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: will surely practice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TF has [insecure](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#insecure) option:

> Explicitly allow the provider to perform "insecure" SSL requests. If omitted, the **default value is false**.

So by default, only https is used. You would have to set this option to true to enable http.

Comment: The article mainly talks about Provider config, not 100% sure that Provider & Remote backend uses the same mechanism to send details over internet; however it is good to know that SSL is default.

Comment: @Zuntoo It's same. Do you really think that state file would be send to s3 in plain text by default over the Internet? This would expose a lot of secrets and lead to huge security hacks. In othewords, if this was the case, terraform would be long forgotten and abandoned by now.